# Flutter Two scrolls in one page

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make two scrolls in one page, the first horizontal, the second vertical, as in the photo.
Share the options, thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3wkc.png)

Comment: Could show some code you may have tried that does not work?

Comment: not yet done, want to know how to do this

Answer (score 1):

As Aman Kumar mentioned above, I think that two listviews is the way to go. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OMkb.gif) of them in use.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: 
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    // Each half has a different scroll direction
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )

                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    // Each half has a different scroll direction
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 160.0,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                  ),
                
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Alice, how can I raise the bottom scroll to the top level of the screen?

Comment: In the example I provided, if you replace the ```Expanded``` directly above the first ```ListView``` with a ```SizedBox``` and give it a specified height, you can limit its size to the upper section similar to your provided example.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can follow a layout like this. It will work all you have to do is adjust the heights.

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      //for horizontal scroll
      Container(
        height: 150.0,  //adjust it yourself
        width: 300.0,  //adjust it yourself
        //you can make it responsive if you use media query 
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              //Your children for horizontal scroll
            ],
          ),
        ),



      ),

      SizedBox(
        height: 10.0,
      ),
      
      //For vertical scroll
      Container(
        height: 750.0,  //adjust it yourself
        width: 300.0,  //adjust it yourself
        //you can make it responsive if you use media query 
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //Your children for vertical scroll
            ],
          ),
        ),



      ),


    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: with this code you can fasten a vertical scroll to the very top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

The Image seems to have two `ListView`'s, i.e one horizontally and second vertically.

```
ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.Horizontal,         // Default is Axis.Vertical
    children:<Widget>[
         item1(),
         item2(),
    ])
```

If you want to scroll everything vertically as one, as well as maintain scroll functionality individually, you should try [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html)

```
CustomScrollView{
 slivers: []
}
```