# Flutter how to implement multiple scrolling items is same screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a screen with a column that contains 2 items and a list below.
i want to make the first item (1) always scroll up below the appbar or down, doesn't care if the list is empty or full.
the second item (2) should always be visible while scrolling the list items.
see image how can i implement this in flutter

[image]

Comment: You can take a reference through this link this will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62888159/flutter-two-scrolls-in-one-page

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you do is to look at `Sliver*` series of built-in Flutter classes. They give you a great amount of flexibility when it comes to scrolling behavior. Here is a great documentation that demonstrates what I mean: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/slivers